# fill datatable from csv

Tags: asp.net, csv

I'm trying here to fill dataTable from csv file. But when I'll bind it dataTable to GridView, gridview is empty. Any idea where I'm wrong? Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    bool isFirstRowHeader = true;
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"D:\WebApplication10\WebApplication10\Students.csv");
    string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
              @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
              ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
    {

        dt.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        //if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        //{
        //    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        //    {
        //        string i = row[0].ToString();
        //        string i1 = row[1].ToString();
        //        string i2 = row[2].ToString();
        //        string i3 = row[3].ToString();
        //    }
        //}
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Comment: Press F12. Do you see any errors? You need to undertake basic troubleshooting: Is the code called? Is the file accessible? Does the adapter fill? I don't see `GridView1` being instantiated here.

Comment: Make sure that gridview autogeneratecolumns is true

Comment: @Santosh, autogeneratecolumns is true

Comment: @Santosh, excel file has 5 columns, here in gridview it gives me one empty column

Comment: When you pressed F12 what did you see?